# jQuery // Can you call multiple functions in $(document).on(....?

Tags: jquery, dom, hover

Is there anyway that this would work? I know that this can be done with just a `.hover()` function, but my results are generated with ajax.

**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OWxEpa)**

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.result',
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("result_hover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("result_hover");
  }
);
```

```css
.result_hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="result">
  Result
</h1>
```

Comment: i mean, you can call `.on(` multiple times, accomplishing the same goal.

Comment: Why jQuery at all for a simple hover effect? `.result:hover { color: red }` ([codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrMGOX))

Comment: @Andreas I know but the hover on that element will add/remove a class on another elem, not the one hovered, what I wanted to know was if its possible to do with the code i provided

Comment: And the code you've provided "cries" for a CSS solution ;)

Comment: Anyone with basic css skills would know that this is possible and not what i was looking for

Comment: So we're supposed to "know" what you're actually looking for? Add a class to another element, fetch another resource, trigger an alert or simply change the color of the hovered element... [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [jQuery.hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/):

> The .hover() method binds handlers for both mouseenter and mouseleave events.

If you are interested only in one handler you can use [toggleClass(className, state)](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className-state).

So you can do:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.result', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass("result_hover", e.type == 'mouseenter');
});
```

```css
.result_hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h1 class="result">
  Result
</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks but i knew about this, was just asking if its possible with the code I provided. But i think that's not possible

Comment: Wow the second option is exactly what I looked for! Thanks a lot @gaetanoM

Comment: Quick question, "e.type == 'mouseenter'" why does it need this?

Comment: @Eli the second parameter of toggleClass is used to say if the class must be added or removed.